# CIDR vs Classful subnetting

Tags: networking, subnet, cidr

I was studying about Classful addressing with subnetting and Classless addressing but I am not able to clearly understand the difference/advantages between the two of them.

Suppose I have a company wants only 32 public IP addresses I can give them a Class C address with a subnet of 27 bits. Similarly I could give them a CIDR subnet to achieve the same result.

|`What is my advantage in using CIDR?`

| `Why was CIDR required even after subnetting can achieve the same result?`

| `Shortcomings of subnetting with classful addresses.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Network classes were killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking doesn't use network classes. Please let them rest in peace.

Comment: @RonMaupin That is exactly my question why invent CIDR if subnetting could accomplish this task?

Comment: Subnetting could not. Given an available Class A address, an RIR would have to assign the entire thing to an AS, but CIDR allows it to be broken up into different ASes. Don't confuse how you can subnet within a single company with how Inter-Domain routing happens.

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing a couple of concepts. Inter-Domain routing under network classes required that entire address class blocks be assigned to a single entity. There was no way to route inter-domain traffic except by class. You could subnet within a single entity, but you could not divide a classful block between entities.

All CIDR is doing is saying that the classes no longer exist, and you can break up what used to be a classful address block among different entities.

Network classes no longer exist, and they really are studied only for historical purposes. Learn how to subnet using CIDR first (become expert at it), then you can learn about network classes as a history lesson.

- Class A starts with first bit `0`
- Class B starts with first two bits `10`
- Class C starts with first three bits `110`
- Class D starts with first four bits `1110`
- Class E starts with first four bits `1111`

Comment: Great explanation as usual ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Class based addressing basically divides the total IPv4 range into five classes : Class A through E; Whereas CIDR is based on concept of subnetting.

In your example, your company wants 32 public ip addresses.
If we assign them a class C address, for example 192.168.2.0, their company reserves all IP addresses in range 192.168.2.1 - 192.168.2.254. But they only want 32 ip addresses which means 223 addresses will be wasted. This is the constraint of classful addressing.

Now if we look at just subnetting, class c ip address has default subnet of 255.255.255.0 so if we divide the range of 192.168.2.0 in 6 subnets each containing 32 available ip addresses your problem is solved. But, if we take this example to higher level we will require CIDR.

According to traditional subnetting,  we can not combine the addresses from the networks 192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.0 because the netmask for class C addresses is 255.255.255.0. However, using CIDR notation, we can combine these blocks by referencing this chunk as 192.168.2.0/23.

This specifies that there are 23 bits used for the network portion that we are referring to. With this, the 24th bit can be either 0 or 1 and it will still match, because the network block only cares about the first 23 digits.

CIDR allows more control over addressing continuous blocks of IP addresses. This is much more useful than the subnetting we talked about originally.

Your example only requires subnetting but if we require large amount of addresses that span over class B through class C ranges, we will require CIDR instead.

Comment: What does this portion mean? According to traditional subnetting, we can not combine the addresses from the networks 192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.0 because the netmask for class C addresses is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: @sijo0703 According to traditional subnetting, the networks 192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.0 would be considered separate subnets because they have different network addresses (192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.0, respectively) and the same subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

Comment: @sijo0703  However, using CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing) notation, it is possible to combine these two subnets by using a subnet mask of 255.255.254.0, which is equivalent to a CIDR prefix length of /23. This would result in a single subnet with a network address of 192.168.2.0 and a broadcast address of 192.168.3.255, and would allow for up to 512 host addresses (510 usable) within the subnet.

Answer (score 0):

IP Addresses have stayed the same.  What has changed is "How devices can determine Network and Node part from an IP Address.  With classful IP Address based processing, the number of bits assigned to network and host parts were fixed. For example when processing ip addresses using classes concept, the system will first determine the class of the IP Address and then use predetermined subnet mask to determine the network portion and host portion.
For class A first octet is network bit which allows 126 networks to be represented.

Due to restrictions on number of hosts and networks imposed by classes, you can define your own subtask mask which represent the network and host part of an IP address regardless which IP Address class you are using. The way that subnet mask is represented in text is called the "CIDR Notation".